# preinstalled iOS apps in other languages

Tags: ios, internationalization

I am configuring an iPad with the apple configurator 2 on my mac book. I want to hide a few preinstalled apps like "tips" or "messages". The system language of my mac book is Spanish, so all app names are displayed in Spanish, while the iPad's language is English. Now I don't know what to type in the filter box in order to mach "tips".

How can I find out the Spanish names for preinstalled iOS apps? There should be a list of those apps somewhere with their localised names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go here

https://support.apple.com/kb/SP692?locale=en_US

And switch the language to spanish

[image]